# How to delay PM2 autostart at boot?

Tags: linux, debian, autostart

I am running the latest version of Debian on an Intel NUC and I've setup PM2 autostart at boot with

```
pm2 startup
```

For my needs I need to delay its start by let's say 30 seconds.

How to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably figured this out by now, but for others who come here the answer is quite simple.

- You just open your shell script file, which is the one that the PM script runs upon start.
- In here you simply put in a "sleep", for the 30 seconds simply write

  ```
  sleep 30s
  ```

  at the top of your `.sh` file.

I used this to open my magic mirror after 30s, so I was sure my Pi connected to the internet before opening the app. My `.sh` file looks like this:

```bsh
sleep 30s
cd ./MagicMirror
DISPLAY=:0 npm start
```

See this link for more info; https://www.lifewire.com/use-linux-sleep-command-3572060